# How to move all lines starting from string to the top of the text file in Bash

Tags: awk, sed, command-line

I have a text file containing text data. I'd like to move all lines starting from XY: and OTP XY: to the top of the file. How can I do this in Bash using sed, awk, other?

Comment: Noting that bash is just a/your shell, and is not an editor.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `ed` (note: this modifies `file` in place; to output the edited file to standard output instead change `wq` to `,p q`):

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^\(\|OTP \)XY:/m0' wq | ed -s file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
{ grep -E '^(OTP )?XY:' input_file; grep -E -v '^(OTP )?XY:' input_file; } > ouput_file
```

The 2 `grep` commands filter the `input_file` with an without (`-v`) the wanted pattern.

The `{ ... } > output_file` stores both  `grep`output to a file.

Comment: It did work only for `OTP XY:` But I just realised that I need to move line starting from string and one line below.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be to use `awk`, for example:

```
awk -v re='^OTP XY:|^XY:'  'NR==FNR && $0 ~ re; NR!=FNR && $0 !~ re' file file
```

The above uses a single process, never stores more than a single line in memory, but does two passes on the file (it reads it twice).

If one of the two patterns is rather unlikely in the file, i.e. small enough to fit in ram, you could use something like this:

```
awk  '/^OTP XY:|^XY:/{print;next} {a = $0 ORS a};END{printf "%s", a}' file
```

This also uses a single process, this time a single pass of the file is made, but the memory usage could increase quite a bit depending on size/contents of the file.

Comment: First line is moving only OTP XY: to the top, but without the one line below. The second line is not doing anything.

Comment: @SynRomana Could you edit your question to add samples of the input and expected outputs? I did some tests here and it seemed to work...

Comment: @SynRomana also what is the output of `awk -v` on your system?

Comment: `awk -v`
`awk: option -v lacks argument` it is Raspbian

Comment: Sample input:`#DATA:-1,XY: AAA`  
`random text`  
`#DATA:-1,XY: AABB`  
`random text`

Comment: I don't know how to break the like in above comment. Double spaces doesn't work. However: lines beginning with # are top lines containing desired string and the random text lines are one line below.